# How to make a ActionBar like Google Play that fades in when scrolling

Tags: android, android-actionbar, transparent, android-actionbar-compat

How to make transparent or translucent ActionBar like Google Play that fades in or out when scrolling using `windowActionBarOverlay`?

**Check the following screenshots**

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work", is there an error, an unexpected result? AVD or real device?

Comment: Check this [ObservableScrollView][1] it should help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685847/how-overlay-an-image-on-scrolling-android

Comment: this link was helpful for me https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar. May be this will be helpful for others!

Answer (score 32):

The following is the code I used in the app I am working

You will have to use the `OnScrollChanged` function in your `ScrollView`. `ActionBar` doesn't let you set the opacity , so set a background drawable on the actionbar and you can change its opacity based on the amount of scroll in the scrollview. I have given an example workflow

The function sets gives the appropriate alpha for the view locationImage based on its position WRT window .

`this.getScrollY()` gives you how much the `scrollView` has scrolled

```
public void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    // Code ...
    locationImage.setAlpha(getAlphaForView(locationImageInitialLocation- this.getScrollY()));
}


private float getAlphaForView(int position) {
    int diff = 0;
    float minAlpha = 0.4f, maxAlpha = 1.f;
    float alpha = minAlpha; // min alpha
    if (position > screenHeight)
        alpha = minAlpha;
    else if (position + locationImageHeight < screenHeight)
        alpha = maxAlpha;
    else {
        diff = screenHeight - position;
        alpha += ((diff * 1f) / locationImageHeight)* (maxAlpha - minAlpha); // 1f and 0.4f are maximum and min
                                            // alpha
        // this will return a number betn 0f and 0.6f
    }
    // System.out.println(alpha+" "+screenHeight +" "+locationImageInitialLocation+" "+position+" "+diff);
    return alpha;
}
```

EDIT : I have added an example working sample at https://github.com/ramanadv/fadingActionBar , you can have a look at it.

[image]

Comment: I tried to run your example working sample at https://github.com/ramanadv/fadingActionBar . But the output is different from your screenshot. Is showing transparent action bar. No fading effect !!

Comment: Which device are you trying to run it on and which android version ?

Comment: I think setOnScrollChange is available on API 23+

Comment: Has anybody expressed this as a Behavior?

Answer (score 8):

Please check this library https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar which implements the cool fading action bar effect that you want

Comment: Note that this does not work with Android 5 Toolbar. Only works with Actionbar.

Comment: Hope this links help someone for many solutions

https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version or

http://snowdream.github.io/awesome-android/

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 8):

This library helps for animation https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 7):

[Official Google DeveloperDocumentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

[image]

*action bar in overlay mode.*

**Enable Overlay Mode**

To enable overlay mode for the action bar, you need to create a custom theme that extends an existing action bar theme and set the android:windowActionBarOverlay property to true.

*For Android 3.0 and higher only*

If your minSdkVersion is set to 11 or higher, your custom theme should use Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

*For Android 2.1 and higher*

If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on devices running versions lower than Android 3.0, your custom theme should use Theme.AppCompat theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

*Specify Layout Top-margin*

When the action bar is in overlay mode, it might obscure some of your layout that should remain visible. To ensure that such items remain below the action bar at all times, add either margin or padding to the top of the view(s) using the height specified by actionBarSize. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is official documentation on how to achieve this effect:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Edit:
There is an open source library ObservableScrollView with a lot of open source demos with different ActionBar effects, including the ones you mentioned. It's a great resource: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a CoordinatorLayout in your layout xml you should checkout [this article](http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout) describing how to handle scrolls and make other views react to them.

There is an example accomplishing what you asked for, if you add your imageview as a child of the CollapsingToolbarLayout all the magic is handled automatically and you can even some parameters like the scrim color, minimum height to start collapsing, etc:

[image]

Comment: That link had exactly what I was looking for. My toolbar wasn't scrolling in sync with my NestedScrollView, but adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the NestedScrollView did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Using AbsListView scroll listener we can achieve for listview simply without using other complicated library or ScrollView

set scroll listener to list view

```
public class PagedScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private View mTopHideView; // represent header view

     @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
        mScrollState = scrollState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

        if (mActionBar != null && mTopHideView != null && mListView != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, getScrollY() + "");
            int currentY = getScrollY();

            final int headerHeight = mTopHideView.getHeight() - mActionBar.getHeight();
            final float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(currentY, 0), headerHeight) / headerHeight;
            final int newAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);
            Log.i(TAG, newAlpha + " alpha");
            mActionBarDrawaqble.setAlpha(newAlpha);
}}


public void setActionBarRefernce(ActionBar actionBar, View topHideView, float actionBarHeight, ListView listView) {
        mActionBar = actionBar;
        mActionBarHeight = actionBarHeight;
        mTopHideView = topHideView;
        mListView = listView;
        mActionBarDrawaqble = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.google_plus_red));
        mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(mActionBarDrawaqble);
        mActionBarDrawaqble.setAlpha(0);
    }

   public int getScrollY() {
        View c = mListView.getChildAt(0);
        if (c == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int firstVisiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int top = c.getTop();

        int headerHeight = 0;
        if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
            headerHeight = mTopHideView.getHeight();
        }

        return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
    }

}
```

// **Note :** Don't forget to call **setActionBarRefernce method ** of custom listener

Answer (score -6):

On webView:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToolbar(String scrollY, String imgWidth) {
    int int_scrollY = Integer.valueOf(scrollY);
    int int_imgWidth = Integer.valueOf(imgWidth);

    String clr;
    if (int_scrollY<=int_imgWidth-actionBarHeight) {
        clr = Integer.toHexString(int_scrollY * 255 / (int_imgWidth-actionBarHeight));
    }else{
        clr = Integer.toHexString(255);
    }

    toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#"+clr+"9CCC65")));
}
```