# How overlay an image on scrolling android

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm new in android development and I would like to do a layout like this image below transparent and translucent Toolbar

[image: Check This Image]

Please could I have some pointers to start me off?

Comment: search for fading action bar on google.You'll get plenty of links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a ActionBar like Google Play that fades in when scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424818/how-to-make-a-actionbar-like-google-play-that-fades-in-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this one may help you https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView