# Name of the layout or how it's done?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

In short I want a preview similar to Google Plays, where you can slide up and the top image/video preview fades back and the rest of the view is moved up.

[image: Preview]

I've got a view that I want to be hiden like the video in this example, the action bar can remain stationary at all times, but I need the bottom part to be dragable.

I can't seem to find out which layout that is, or how it is done, all I managed to find were unrelated such as ViewPager. My current min sdk version is 18, the compile version is 21.

Comment: if you want to ask a question then first post your code too so that we could see what have you tried so far ... ?

Comment: @Darkie : As the OP has no idea what the layout type is or how the effect is achieved, I'd consider this a valid question even without the OP posting any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the code I used in the app I am working

You will have to use the `OnScrollChanged` function in your `ScrollView`. ActionBar doesn't let you set the opacity , so set a background drawable on the actionbar and you can change its opacity based on the amount of scroll in the scrollview. I have given an example workflow

The function sets gives the appropriate alpha for the view locationImage based on its position WRT window .

`this.getScrollY()` gives you how much the scrollView has scrolled

```
public void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    // Code ...
    locationImage.setAlpha(getAlphaForView(locationImageInitialLocation- this.getScrollY()));
}


private float getAlphaForView(int position) {
    int diff = 0;
    float minAlpha = 0.4f, maxAlpha = 1.f;
    float alpha = minAlpha; // min alpha
    if (position > screenHeight)
        alpha = minAlpha;
    else if (position + locationImageHeight < screenHeight)
        alpha = maxAlpha;
    else {
        diff = screenHeight - position;
        alpha += ((diff * 1f) / locationImageHeight)* (maxAlpha - minAlpha); // 1f and 0.4f are maximum and min
                                            // alpha
        // this will return a number betn 0f and 0.6f
    }
    // System.out.println(alpha+" "+screenHeight +" "+locationImageInitialLocation+" "+position+" "+diff);
    return alpha;
}
```

You can download an example working sample at https://github.com/ramanadv/fadingActionBar

Credit: [CommandSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424818/how-to-make-a-actionbar-like-google-play-that-fades-in-when-scrolling)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this only for the actionbar? I'm more interested in the preview image/video that seems to move behind the bottom part of the layout

Comment: Yes, noticed that. That is not supported in my given source. I know about another library which works exactly what you want. But I didn't test that. Thats why I didn't share. You can check this. Hopefully it will help.
Check this: https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar