# Overlay image on Action Bar

Tags: java, android, image, android-actionbar, material-design

How do I overlay image over an **Action Bar** and **status bar**? Here is what I want it to look like -

[image: Target]

I read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html) but it gives different results than what I want. The Action Bar still has some opacity and the status bar has no effect at all.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Add these two lines of code to your styles-v21.xml file:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Edit:
You want it in the v21 file because Android versions below 5.0 don't support this.

Also...for Material Design, you should be using a **ToolBar** not an **Action Bar**. Here's how to change the color of a Toolbar.

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29122573/1276495) answer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25425938/1276495) one worked perfectly in my project.

This library is also great to explore:
https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

Comment: While that listed library is good, there's an even more powerful one here: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: No problem! I found it a couple days ago and implemented it into my app. It's beautiful! There's also some other types of things like FlexibleSpace as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this will work, is there any way to do this without scrolling? Can I add a fixed image?