# How do I implement Android Activity Transitions in lower version?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to implement the mentioned shared elements transition in lower versions of android also. Is there any third party library to implement this?

Video : [Activity Transition](http://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.mp4)

Ref : http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30421084/1276495) answer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25425938/1276495) one is not a library but a **easiest example** that perfectly in my project.

This library is also great to explore:
https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

Or even more powerful one is [here](http://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView).

Comment: Your snippet are useful but I need to implement the transition with shared elements.