# Android fading toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

Does anyone know how to create a fading toolbar with an image on an activity with `RecyclerView`?

I've been googling everywhere and haven't found a working solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424818/how-to-make-a-actionbar-like-google-play-that-fades-in-when-scrolling might help

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library.

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

It is very complete and has many examples, including the one you need (Fadding toolbar).

Hope it helps you!!